# Does writing about achieving future goals provide health benefits?

Tags: psychology, goal-setting

Gregory Ciotti writes in The ["Psychological Benefits of Writing"](https://www.helpscout.net/blog/benefits-of-writing/):

> Research by Laura King shows that writing about achieving future goals and dreams can make people happier and healthier...

Is the claim that there are health benefits to be gained by writing about achieving future goals correct?